# AngularJS click propagates into d3 drag event of previously dragged element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm working on a AngularJS application and I've been struggling with the following problem for a day now, and I still can't figure it out. I've tried all variations of stopPropagation() and/or preventDefault(), still getting nowhere. Namely, I have an svg group:

```
 <g id="thursday" class="parent"> \
    <rect fill="#483e37" fill-opacity="0.6" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" width="95" height="30" x="0" y="90" /> \
    <rect fill="#b3b3b3" fill-opacity="0.6" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" width="650" height="30" x="95" y="90" /> \
    <text font-family="Helvetica Neue" font-size="20" font-weight="300" fill="#FFFFFF "> \
        <tspan text-anchor="middle" x="47.5" y="115">Thursday</tspan> \
    </text> \
</g> \
```

Now, this group has an on('click') event registered:

```
  d3.select('#thursday').on('click', function() {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      ...
  }
```

And also allows insertion of circles:

```
  group.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', xpos)
    .attr('cy', ypos)
    .attr('r', this.radius)
    .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) { return d; })
        .on('dragstart', function(d) {
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            d.dragstart = d3.mouse(this); // store this
        })
        .on('drag', function(d) {
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            self.mouseDragCallback(this, self, d);
        })
        .on('dragend', function() {
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        })
     );
```

And after I drag such a circle, sometimes, when I click away on the rectangle in the same group, the click event propagates straight to the d3 drag event on the circle. Anyone knows how I can solve this issue? It is very strange that even though a dragend event is received on the circle, when this bug occurs, it jumps straight to drag, skipping the dragstart event. Thank you very much in advance!